# What do I do about an untidy engineering school tutor visiting my company soon?

Tags: internship, student, employment

I'm currently doing my final-year internship in a relatively big company which has a dress code.  My engineering school tutor is required to come once to my workplace, and this is probably going to happen during the next month.  He is very untidy and lacks communication skills.  I feel that if he shows up in his normal manner, it's going to reflect badly on me and hurt my chances of being hired after my internship.

You might ask, "Why did you choose him as his tutor?".  Generally, our school assigns tutors without consulting with the students.

What might be a reasonable solution to this potential disaster?

Comment: I will not reflect badly on you. Why would you think it would?

Comment: Because he's probably going to walk through the open space with me and we're going to meet with my director. I don't know, I just have this feeling that it won't leave the best impression on my colleagues and hierarchy...

Comment: As long as you remain professional and try to minimize any awkwardness that your tutor may have when speaking to your seniors, you will be just fine. Look at this as a good experience for you... you will sometimes have individuals on your team who are socially awkward and being able to mediate in a way that makes them and outsiders comfortable is a great skill to build in business.

Comment: You could just tell him to dress up a little. That being said since you said "Cheers", you must not be from the US.  I am in Silicon Valley and this kind of thing is common place. At UC Berkeley, my semi-famous Professor and Computer Science Undergraduate Director used to show up in his sandals and would take them off and would lecture barefoot.

Comment: I guess it's inevitable.. Thanks for the positive POV.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk yeah it's the perks of the US, you guys are so informal and laid back !

Comment: Laid back, yes. But sometimes, being laid back can be a power move. Showing too much anxiety in an unusual situation like that can definitely be very career limiting and may prevent you from becoming more than a worker bee. So even in a foreign country (I am originally from France), I would make sure not to be overly apologetic, or overly anxious, at having a guy dressed like a bum having been my technical tutor. Take his visit in stride. Don't show off your insecurity or your anxiety. So don't try to hide him. And don't try to cut his visit short either.

Comment: @MarchToSuccess I used to teach class in shorts and flip flops. Usually CS/Engr academic types are more about getting results than keeping up their appearance.

Comment: Why would he be coming to your workplace? That is not normal. We have lots of interns and their professors never come here, nor would they be allowed to come here.

Comment: How many interns has your company had, over the years?  I would expect that they have seen such situations before.  Especially since (in the US, at least) communication skills and formal dress seem to have an inverse correlation to technical skill.

Comment: You might look for the humorous side of this.  If you can find one, you should be fine.  That does *not* mean try to make a humorous comment about the situation, when you don't really find it funny.  If you can't laugh about it, then you're best to "take it in stride" as others have mentioned.  If you can see the funny side of it, that will communicate itself without any effort on your part.

Comment: @Socrates Agreed this isn't common in the US at all, but my colleagues who did their degrees in the UK were surprised that my thesis adviser never paid me a visit at my graduate internship.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Talk to your tutor.

Simply tell him, "The office has a dress code of (Suit & tie / Oxfords and slacks / Button-up Shirt and Khakis).  It's mandatory."  Then just let it go at that.  If he's determined to defy it, continuing to "nudge" him will only aggravate things.

Comment: "The office has a dress code of (Suit & tie / Oxfords and slacks / Button-up Shirt and Khakis). It's mandatory." I wouldn't say that. What's mandatory for an employee is rarely mandatory for a guest. Tell him what's mandatory for you as an intern and then suggest to him what he should wear (one notch below what you're supposed to be wearing yourself should be good). And like you said, I wouldn't press the issue if he disregards what you said. After all, he's your guest, and if he's not meeting you at the White House, or at 55 Downing Street, he probably won't be stopped at the door.

Comment: The last person to edit my post wrote the phrase... I guess I'll try to make a subtle hint about the dress code in my next email to my tutor. Thanks :)

Comment: @MarchToSuccess - Thanks for bringing that up.  I reworded it to remove the euphemism.  I'll edit this answer to drop the comment about it.

Answer (score 6):

It won't (shouldn't) impact on you. You should treat both the tutor and everyone else with respect irrespective of mannerisms or appearance. But at the end of the day if I was the director I wouldn't care about the tutors appearance, and it would in no way make a difference to the intern.

One thing I will mention is that just because the tutor is untidy in his own environment, does not mean he's happy to go somewhere else like that. I'm heavily tattooed and I tend to stroll around in shorts and a t-shirt. But if I was going somewhere with one of my trainees to meet someone important to the trainee I would make an effort with my appearance and look totally different. Your tutor is more than likely the same.

Answer (score 3):

If I'd be your boss, I'd evaluate you only by what *you* are, what your skills are, how much you know about the job and how quickly you learn what you don't know.

I'd never evaluate you based on your tutor, your family background, your gender, your race, your clothes (as long as they are not completely out of the place).

You may go ahead and tell your tutor about the few things that are your office's custom, like the dress-code (if there is one). It is your responsibility to inform him about potential things that he may not know of. However, he is an adult himself and it is not your responsibility to ensure that he follows what you told him.